# Xamarin.Android listview getPosition method returns object

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Listview and I want to take the item at clicked position. But GetItemAtPosition method return Object and casting is not working. I assigned it to a "var" type variable but in this case I can not get properties and method of Person object. What sould I do? Thank you.

```
persons.Add(new Person("Random Name", "Merhaba", Resource.Drawable.image));
        persons.Add(new Person("Random Name", "Merhaba", Resource.Drawable.image));

        ListView listView = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView);

        PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this,persons);

        listView.Adapter = adapter;



        listView.ItemClick += (object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            Person person = listView.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position); // this line gives error. (Cannot implictly convert type "Java.Lang.Object" to Person)
            Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, person.Name, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ChatActivity));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
        };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrqtO.png)

Comment: But I've solved the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use listview ItemSelected

```
        private void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var obj = (Person)e.SelectedItem;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDE could not convert the type of object in Adapter when building the project .So you could explicit convert it manually.

```
Person person = (Person)listView.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. But I've solved the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You could share your answer

Comment: I define the person list as static then use it to access each index.

Comment: Post it as answer and accept it , or I can edit my answer then you accept it .